# Key down event does not update variable inside while loop

Tags: python, animation, tkinter

I'm currently making an animation on the canvas using tkinter with python and running into some issues. The relevant portion of my code is below.

```
k = 0
dirX, dirY = 1, 0

def LeftButton(event):
    dirX = -abs(dirX)

c.bind("<Left>", LeftButton)

while 1:
    k %= 6
    #show one frame of animation and hide the rest
    c.itemconfig(pc[k], state=tk.NORMAL)
    c.itemconfig(pc[(k+1) % 6], state=tk.HIDDEN)
    c.itemconfig(pc[(k+2) % 6], state=tk.HIDDEN)
    c.itemconfig(pc[(k+3) % 6], state=tk.HIDDEN)
    c.itemconfig(pc[(k+4) % 6], state=tk.HIDDEN)
    c.itemconfig(pc[(k+5) % 6], state=tk.HIDDEN)
    #move all of the frames to the same location
    c.move(pc[k],dirX*5,dirY*5)
    c.move(pc[(k+1) % 6],dirX*5,dirY*5)
    c.move(pc[(k+2) % 6],dirX*5,dirY*5)
    c.move(pc[(k+3) % 6],dirX*5,dirY*5)
    c.move(pc[(k+4) % 6],dirX*5,dirY*5)
    c.move(pc[(k+5) % 6],dirX*5,dirY*5)
    
    k += 1
    #update the canvas
    c.update()
    time.sleep(.075)
```

Basically, `pc` is a numpy array of image objects on the canvas and at each index is a different image frame of the animation. Every .075 seconds it shows one frame and hides all of the others, and then increments the position of all of them. I am trying to build it so that when I press the left key, `dirX` becomes negative so my animation goes to the left. The animation is working fine, but the problem is that anything outside of the while loop is fixed, i.e. pressing a button does nothing. It may be that I am binding them wrong, but I binded it to a mouse click which I have done before and it still didn't work. Is there a better way to animate than a while loop? 
One way I considered is instead of having `while 1:` I can put `while not (code for keydown event):`, but I don't know the code for a keydown event and I just want the variable `dirX` to update and then reinitiate the while loop, which is also problematic. What is the best way I can fix this? Thank you

**Edit**

I ran a test to see if `LeftButton` would print anything if the event was triggered, and it didn't. I think this means that while the code is running through the while loop it isn't checking or handling events.

Comment: You should declare `global dirX` in the function. I am actually surprised that your program does not crash,

Comment: Me too. I'm just learning Python. I just declared `global dirX` in `LeftButton` but it didn't work.

Comment: In tkinter, use the `after` method instead of the sleep loop. As you mentioned, the while loop is blocking events. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method

Comment: @Mike67 thank you. This worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a GUI program, you already have the `mainloop` and any additional infinitely running loop will block the application.
Instead, try using the `after` function of tkinter.

```
def animation():
    # your itemconfig, move commands and
    # other animation logic.
    c.after(75, animation)

# start animation
animation()
```

This will tell tkinter to continue with the mainloop, and after 75ms, call the animation function again. `after` is often called from the `root` widget, but your canvas widget should work, too.